# Check if value exists in JSON array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3

```
CREATE TABLE js_testt (
    id SERIAL,
    tids json
);

INSERT INTO js_testt (tids) values ('{"flat": ["11", "22", "33", "44"], "promo": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]}');
```

Based on the above example, how can I find whether the value "33" exists in table under json key "flat".

Answer (score 0):

First I have bad news, that this is ot very developed in 9.2.  If you can't go to 9.3 you will have to roll your own.

You really want to write functions to process json (that take json in and return values out) and do this in a language like plperlu or plv8js.  Make sure the functions are immutable (i.e always produce the same output with no side effects, given the same input) and mark them as such.

Then you can call those functions, index the results, etc.